# Recovering past features with Git

Tags: git

I have a question regarding how to solve my particular situation with Git.

Say I have a commit where *some feature* is implemented. I tag this commit "Feature Implemented". (the master was there in the beginning)
Then I started a branch "Check time", where I deactivated the feature, and I added some kind of time checking (not present in the original). I committed that.

First question: How do I merge my feature with the time checking? I mean if you do a simple merge (As I did - I explain this later) you will do a fast-forward merge and the feature will be deactivated.

---

So I -mistakenly- did that. I checkout master and fast-forward merged (so now master is same as "Check time". My situation is that now master has the feature deactivated and a nice time checking operating. The feature is implemented in a previous commit.

How do I get a commit where the feature is active *and* the time checking is present too? ( I don't want to lose the time checking as with a revert)

-->(FI)--->(master)(Check Time)

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix would be, if you know the exact commit, to cherry-pick it to your current branch.

That would force Git to re-apply the changes introduced in that commit, restoring your feature.

See [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).